# Facing camera faceup UIDeviceOrientation issue when use UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios

I have an app that works on landscape, already in the store, and decided to add a camera for a certain new feature in my next update.
with an iPad 2 the image inside the camera appears rotated **90** degrees in clockwise direction.
Once the picture is taken it appears it's saved correct position.
Needed is that always there should be a landscape mode,while taking picture and once image is clicked and saved.But image inside the camera appears to be in Portrait view. I also checked the device orientation i.e faceUp orientation.

I have used the below code to manage the orientation but could not resolve

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
// UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp )
{
    return NO;
}
else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown)
{
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I think the default camera view (the one opened via UIImagePickerController) is portrait only. However, there is a mechanism for adding custom camera overlays. You might look into that for some hints.